# Does F# have row polymorphism (or something similar?)

Tags: .net, f#, ocaml, f#-3.0

Does F# have row polymorphism or something similar?  Specifically, in OCaml, we can write a function like

```ml
# let foo x = x#num+2;;
val foo : < num : int; .. > -> int = <fun>
```

Basically, the function `foo` can accept any object that contains a method `num` of type `int`.  I'm not sure how to do something similar in F#.  If possible, I'd like to avoid explicit subtyping through inheritance.  Specifically, I'm **not** looking for something like this:

```ml
[<AutoOpen>]
module Foo

[<AbstractClass>]
type foo() =
    abstract member num : int

type foo1() =
    inherit foo()
    override this.num = 2
    member this.char = 'a'

type foo2() =
    inherit foo()
    override this.num = 3
    member this.string = "abbacadabba"

let f (x:foo) = x.num + 2
```

The reason is that even though we can use objects of type `foo1` and `foo2` inside of `f`, we lose access to their other members, `char` and `string`, respectively.  In order to regain this information, we have to play double dispatch tricks such as with the visitor pattern and I'm trying to avoid this.  Basically, I'm trying to get something like row polymorphism and not subtyping.

Comment: there is something similar [see here under explicit member constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx) but usually you'll want to go with the interface for idiomatic F# IMO

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
let inline foo (a: ^a) = 
    let x = (^a : (member num: int) (a))
    x + 2

type monkey() =
    member x.num = 2
type pig() =
    member x.num = 3

let x = monkey()
let y = pig()

foo x // = 2+2=4
foo y // = 3+2=5
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  From @CarstenKönig's comment above, I understand that these are explicit member constraints.  Now, is there a name for the syntax `(^a : (member num: int) (a))`, or is this something inherently tied to explicit member constraints?  Basically, do we use this backwards syntax where we call the type on the object anywhere else?

Comment: @Carsten König, re your edit, new is optional but I'm not aware of any guideline that says it should not be used, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @PatrickMcDonald to be honest right now I cannot produce an official source but AFAIK it is idiomatic - the compiler will warn you if you don't use new with `IDisposable`s which is a nice thing to have - `new` will tell the reader that it's a resource of some kind that should be *disposed* and the compiler will help you find it , ...

Comment: The [spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/) states implicitly in _6.4.1 Basic Application Expressions_ that the `new` keyword is considered optional: *Application expressions may start with object construction expressions that do not include the `new` keyword...*

Comment: By the way, in response to my own question, the syntax `(^a : (member num: int) (a))` is called a _member constraint invocation expression_ by the spec and is in section 6.4.8.

Comment: @wyer33 also relevant: the `^a` is a *statically resolved type parameter*, sometimes shortened to *SRTP*.